# How to find unassociated records Rails Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have these three models

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscribes
  has_many :groups, through: :subscribes
end
```

```rb
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscribes
  has_many :users, through: :subscribes
end
```

```rb
class Subscribe < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end
```

I want to query in a clean way, all the groups that the user is not in. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If user has `groups` association, it means it has `group_ids` method

```rb
Group.where.not(id: user.group_ids)
```

And also you can explicitly extract such ids

```rb
Group.where.not(id: Subscribe.select(:group_id).where(user_id: user.id))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use the "where" method in ActiveRecord.

For example:

```
Group.where("id NOT IN (?)", user.groups.map(&:id))
```

This would give you all of the groups that the user is not in.

you can also use a subquery for this:

```
Group.where("id NOT IN (SELECT group_id FROM subscribes WHERE user_id = ?)", user.id)
```

This would give you the same result as the previous example, but without using the .map method.
"

Comment: That is awesome. Thank you. I was wondering if there is a way to avoid the `.map`. Especially with very large data sets

Comment: solution amended

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the group ids where the user is not present like below:

```
group_ids = Subscribe.where.not(user_id: user.id).uniq
```

and then find the group records by querying the groups with these ids:

```
groups = Group.where(id: group_ids)
```